ag-grid disable auto unpin
In Ag-grid, when you pin to many columns and there is no more room for horizontal scrolling, the library automatically unpins some columns to free up space.
Is there a way to disable this feature, as I want to implement have something custom?
The main problem is that it also unpins the columns that have lockPinned set to true.

processUnpinnedColumns={() => []}
This is a handle into AgGrid's column processing where you can override what columns should be unpinned due to viewport resizing. In the code above, an empty array of columns is always returned, so no columns will removed when the viewport is resized.
Reference: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/8015#issuecomment-2157827656
